# Errors running Java program

Tags: java, netbeans

Im tying to run my java program using netbeans and im getting this error, any suggestion?

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:181)
    at MainForm.addComponentsToPane(MainForm.java:28)
    at MainForm.createAndShowGUI(MainForm.java:112)
    at MainForm.access$000(MainForm.java:15)
    at MainForm$4.run(MainForm.java:125)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:641)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:602)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:600)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:611)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

this is the code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;




public class MainForm {

    public static void addComponentsToPane(final JFrame frame, Container pane) {
        Color colorGreen = new Color(0, 100, 0);
        Color colorBrown = new Color(150, 100, 0);
        //Color colorBlue = new Color (0, 0, 150);
        //Font font = new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 12);

        pane.setLayout(null);
        pane.setBackground(new Color (255, 255, 170));

        //add image and necessary labels on top left corner
        //SHA Image and label
        ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(MainForm.class.getResource("SHA_logo.gif"));    
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Office of Traffic & Safety", image, JLabel.LEFT);
        label.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.BOTTOM);
        label.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
        label.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 11));
        pane.add(label);
        label.setBounds(50, 10, 130, 100);
        label.setBorder(null);

        //university of maryland image and label\\\
        image = new ImageIcon(MainForm.class.getResource("maryland_flag_round.gif"));   
        label = new JLabel("Univ. of Maryland", image, JLabel.LEFT);
        label.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.BOTTOM);
        label.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
        label.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 11));
        pane.add(label);
        label.setBounds(190, 10, 130, 90);      
        label.setBorder(null);

        //critical lane label
        label = new JLabel("Critical Lane Volume");
        label.setFont(new Font("Arial Narrow", Font.BOLD, 30));
        label.setForeground(colorGreen);
        pane.add(label);
        label.setBounds(50, 90, 250, 50);
        label.setBorder(null);

        label = new JLabel("<html>Please choose the analysis type:</html>");
        label.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 18));
        label.setForeground(colorBrown);
        pane.add(label);
        label.setBounds(25, 130, 300, 70);
        label.setBorder(null);  

        //back and exit buttons
        JButton button1 = new JButton("Interchange");
        JButton button2 = new JButton ("Intersection");
        JButton button3 = new JButton ("Exit");
        pane.add(button1);
        pane.add(button2);
        pane.add(button3);
        button1.setBounds(75, 200, 200, 50);
        button2.setBounds(75, 270, 200, 50);
        button3.setBounds(75, 340, 200, 50);

        //add attap label at bottom left
        image = new ImageIcon(MainForm.class.getResource("attap_logo.gif"));    
        label = new JLabel(image);
        pane.add(label);
        label.setBounds(30, 380, 270, 90);      
        label.setBorder(null);

        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                frame.setVisible(false);
                frame.dispose();
                InterchangeLoad.main(null);
            }
        }); 

        button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                frame.setVisible(false);
                frame.dispose();
                MultipleIntersectionLoad.main(null);
            }
        });

        button3.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                frame.setVisible(false);
                frame.dispose();
            }
        });

    }


    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Critical Lane Volume");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Set up the content pane.
        addComponentsToPane(frame, frame.getContentPane());

        frame.setSize(350, 500);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

It looks like one (or more) of the arguments you are passing into your ImageIcon constructor are null.

EDIT

The exception is occurring at one of these two lines:

```
ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(MainForm.class.getResource("SHA_logo.gif"));
```

or

```
image = new ImageIcon(MainForm.class.getResource("maryland_flag_round.gif"));
```

In either case, the problem is the same: the resource is not being found, and so `null` is being returned by getResource().  Why aren't you just using `new ImageIcon(String filename)`?  I'm not even 100% sure what getResource() is doing.

A few other quick comments (suggestions) on your code:

`pane.setLayout(null);` is not a good idea, I'm not even sure you can just get rid of the LayoutManager like that.

Reusing the same reference (`image` and `label`) multiple times for different objects is bad coding style.  You're not saving any memory by doing that, and the code makes less sense.

Use more descriptive names!  `button1` should probably be called 'interchangeButton' or something along those lines.  For such a small segment of code, no one will get lost, but if you ever work on a larger project, a good naming scheme is vital.

Comment: The real question here is why a null argument is being passed into the constructor... which means that something else is probably wrong with the code.  @user638234, post your code!

Comment: Perhaps passing a null value when an image file was not found?