# create a java program using eclipse, cant run it using netbeans

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Errors running Java program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6417805/errors-running-java-program)

I am currently writing a java program using eclipse. I heard that it is easier to make java gui using netbeans so I want to try to finish this java program using netbeans. However, when i open my project using netbeans and run it, it give me an error. Im tying to use betbeans run the same program that run fine under eclipse.

this is the error:

```
run:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:181)
    at MainForm.addComponentsToPane(MainForm.java:28)
    at MainForm.createAndShowGUI(MainForm.java:112)
    at MainForm.access$000(MainForm.java:15)
    at MainForm$4.run(MainForm.java:125)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:641)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:602)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:600)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:611)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 8 seconds)
```

this is the codes im tying to run:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;




public class MainForm {

    public static void addComponentsToPane(final JFrame frame, Container pane) {
        Color colorGreen = new Color(0, 100, 0);
        Color colorBrown = new Color(150, 100, 0);
        //Color colorBlue = new Color (0, 0, 150);
        //Font font = new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 12);

        pane.setLayout(null);
        pane.setBackground(new Color (255, 255, 170));

        //add image and necessary labels on top left corner
        //SHA Image and label
        ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(MainForm.class.getResource("SHA_logo.gif"));    
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Office of Traffic & Safety", image, JLabel.LEFT);
        label.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.BOTTOM);
        label.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
        label.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 11));
        pane.add(label);
        label.setBounds(50, 10, 130, 100);
        label.setBorder(null);

        //university of maryland image and label\\\
        image = new ImageIcon(MainForm.class.getResource("maryland_flag_round.gif"));   
        label = new JLabel("Univ. of Maryland", image, JLabel.LEFT);
        label.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.BOTTOM);
        label.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
        label.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 11));
        pane.add(label);
        label.setBounds(190, 10, 130, 90);      
        label.setBorder(null);

        //critical lane label
        label = new JLabel("Critical Lane Volume");
        label.setFont(new Font("Arial Narrow", Font.BOLD, 30));
        label.setForeground(colorGreen);
        pane.add(label);
        label.setBounds(50, 90, 250, 50);
        label.setBorder(null);

        label = new JLabel("<html>Please choose the analysis type:</html>");
        label.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 18));
        label.setForeground(colorBrown);
        pane.add(label);
        label.setBounds(25, 130, 300, 70);
        label.setBorder(null);  

        //back and exit buttons
        JButton button1 = new JButton("DIAT");
        JButton button2 = new JButton ("Intersection");
        JButton button3 = new JButton ("Exit");
        pane.add(button1);
        pane.add(button2);
        pane.add(button3);
        button1.setBounds(75, 200, 200, 50);
        button2.setBounds(75, 270, 200, 50);
        button3.setBounds(75, 340, 200, 50);

        //add attap label at bottom left
        image = new ImageIcon(MainForm.class.getResource("attap_logo.gif"));    
        label = new JLabel(image);
        pane.add(label);
        label.setBounds(30, 380, 270, 90);      
        label.setBorder(null);

        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                frame.setVisible(false);
                frame.dispose();
                InterchangeLoad.main(null);
            }
        }); 

        button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                frame.setVisible(false);
                frame.dispose();
                MultipleIntersectionLoad.main(null);
            }
        });

        button3.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                frame.setVisible(false);
                frame.dispose();
            }
        });

    }


    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Critical Lane Volume");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Set up the content pane.
        addComponentsToPane(frame, frame.getContentPane());

        frame.setSize(350, 500);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: Are all the .gif images available?

Comment: Does your file "SHA_logo.gif" exists?

Comment: why are you asking the same thing twice? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6417805/errors-running-java-program

Answer (score 1):

It's not finding your images. Are you sure that you have your images in the same relative position?  Are they in the same location as the MainForm.class file?  Also I would take exception to the comment that it is easier to create a GUI with NetBeans than Eclipse. I've used both and find both fine to use, but I recommend you avoid using any code generation software until you know Swing well. For instance, you would do well to learn how to use the Swing/AWT layout managers and avoiding using null layout/setBounds.

Comment: you are right, the image is not showing up in the left panel under project. This is strange, im using netbeans to open the folder where all my images should be at, but only some images show up while others dont, any suggestion on what should i do?

Comment: @user638234: There is nothing strange about it. NetBeans holds the class files elsewhere and the images need to be with the class files, not the java files.

Answer (score 1):

Your program can't find the file "SHA_logo.gif", so your `new ImageIcon(...)` is `new ImageIcon(null)` and that is causing the NullPointerException.